# Module 'phalcon' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Tags: configuration, ubuntu-14.04, phalcon, php-7

I've installed Phalcon and Phalcon devtool in php7.0, when I type 'Phalcon help' I got a warning message:

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'phalcon' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

I've tried to add 'extension = phalcon.so' in the php.ini file, but I get an error message:

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'phalcon' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'phalcon' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'jsonserializable' not found in Unknown on line 0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I would be appreciate it, if you help me

Answer (score 1):

Remove not needed `extension = phalcon.so`. Load phalcon AFTER json.so

Comment: I removed 'extension = phalcon.so' , and added json.so and restart php7.0-fpm, but still get a warning message: PHP Warning:  Module 'phalcon' already loaded in Unknown on line 0. and tried to add 'extension = phalcon.so' after 'extension = json.so', but I still get the same warning message

Comment: But this error means PHALCON IS ALREADY LOADED. You have two `extension=phalcon.so` you need to remove not needed.

Comment: Ok thank guys, this is solved. my problem is I had 2 file phalcon.ini " 20-phalcon.ini and 30-phalcon.ini " in /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/, and I removed 20-phalcon.ini

Answer (score 0):

If you use Ubuntu 18.04, check in /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/